# Netty Performance Test random requests fail

Tags: tcp, netty

With Jmeter I am generating load on our Netty Http(s) Server. If Jmeter and Netty server on same machine then I don't see any error during the load tests. But in case of server running on network (firewall etc in place), I see some requests are failing randomly.

For certain requests I see **NoHttpResponseException** in Jmeter, see the wireshark many TCP-Retransmissions are there:

[image]

Other requests are failing with **SocketTimeoutException** in Jmeter, here is Wireshark trace image (in this case even response was sent by Netty server with frame number 66070:

[image]

Is it some network setup issue (chances are less as other applications are running there) or some Netty problem? How can I find out the reason?

Comment: Can you ask the local network administrators to run some tests of the network performance?

Comment: Is it maybe because of Tcp packet loss? I am wondering underlying tcp stack ensures reliable packet transmission.